# How to do exact string match while filtering from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as

df

```
   indx   pids
    A    181718,
    B     31718,
    C      1718, 
    D    1235,3456
    E    890654,
```

I want to return a row that matches 1718 exactly.

I tried to do this but as expected it returns rows where the 1718 is subset as well:

`group_df = df.loc[df['pids'].astype(str).str.contains('{},'.format(1718)), 'pids']`

```
   indx   pids
    A    181718,
    B     31718,
    C      1718,
```

When I try to do something like this, it returns empty:

```
cham_geom = df.loc[df['pids'] == '1718', 'pids']
```

Expected output:

```
 indx   pids
  C      1718,
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: `cham_geom = df[df['pids'] == 1718]`

Comment: @anky_91 Great, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, you want to filter if any item in your string (separated by commas) is an exact match with `'1718'`, so `'1891, 1718'` should remain in your filtered DataFrame?

Comment: @ALollz Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try with:

```
df[df.pids.replace('\D','',regex=True).eq('1718')]

  indx   pids
2    C  1718,
```

> '\D' : Any character that is not a numeric digit from 0 to 9.

***EDIT***
Considering the below df:

```
  indx       pids
0    A    181718,
1    B     31718,
2    C      1718,
3    D  1235,3456
4    E    890654,
5    F  3220,1718
```

executing:

```
df[df.pids.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: '1718' in x)]
#if not comma only:-> df[df.pids.str.split("\D").apply(lambda x: '1718' in x)]
```

Gives:

```
  indx       pids
2    C      1718,
5    F  3220,1718
```

Comment: If I have a cell value as `3220,1718,`, I should be able to get that row. How will this code get modified as currently I get for the above case as `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Comment: @Atihska you mean `df.pids.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: '1718' in x)` ?? Check EDIT

Answer (score 2):

there is a method `isin` that matches and returns a dataframe containing True for matched and false for not matching.

Consider the following example

```
>>> found = df.isin(["1718,"])==True
>>> df[found].head(3)
```

this will show the first 3 values matched with 1718

or if you want to match it with only 1 value then you can do so

```
>>> found = df.pids == "1718,"
>>> df[found].head(3)
```

Comment: I want exact match and not a substring match.

Comment: Thats an exact match not a substring using this method you can search a list of words

Comment: If you want to search in one column then you can do like this `found = df[["pids"]].isin(["1718"])==True`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains` with a negative lookbehind, to ensure there are no other digits before `'1718'`

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'indx': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G'},
     'pids': {0: '181718,', 1: '31718,', 2: '1718,', 3: '1235,3456', 4: '890654,', 5: '1231,1718', 6: '1231, 1718'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

#### Code:

```
df.loc[df.pids.str.contains('(?<![0-9])1718')]
```

#### Output:

```
  indx        pids
2    C       1718,
5    F   1231,1718
6    G  1231, 1718
```

Comment: @Atihska I removed the get_dummies as it wasn't smart. But the `.str.contains` should be much faster. Is that still too slow?